# How to specifiy User-defined name in AllowedCustomGrantTypes in an IdentityServer 3

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I would like to give an user-defined custom grant type in an Identity Server version 3.

Reference Doc: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customGrantTypes.html

My Client (In-Memory) Code is

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "ABC Service",
    ClientId = "ABC_SERVICE",
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256()),
    },
    Enabled = true,
    Flow = Flows.Custom,
    AllowedCustomGrantTypes = new List<string>
    {
        "abc_service"
    },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        "read",
        "write",
    },
}
```

My Client Side Code is

```
var client = new TokenClient(
    "https://localhost:2025/core/connect/token",
    "ABC_SERVICE",
    "secret");

var customParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "some_custom_parameter", "some_value" }
};

var result = client.RequestCustomGrantAsync("abc_service", "read", customParams).Result;
```

it gives the error full output

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

If I change the `AllowedCustomGrantTypes` from `"abc_service"` to `"custom"`, it works fine and calling client code too.

```
AllowedCustomGrantTypes = new List<string>
{
    "custom"
}
```

Client Code:

```
var result = client.RequestCustomGrantAsync("custom", "read", customParams).Result;
```

Kindly assist me how to specify the user-defined Custom Grant Type.

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify our user-defined custom grant type in CustomGrantValidator service

```
class CustomGrantValidator : ICustomGrantValidator {
    private IUserService _users;

    public CustomGrantValidator(IUserService users) {
        _users = users;
    }

    Task<CustomGrantValidationResult> ICustomGrantValidator.ValidateAsync(ValidatedTokenRequest request) {
        var param = request.Raw.Get("some_custom_parameter");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param)) {
            return Task.FromResult<CustomGrantValidationResult>(
                new CustomGrantValidationResult("Missing parameters."));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new CustomGrantValidationResult("abc","customGrant"));

    }

    public string GrantType {
        get { return "user-defined-value"; }
    }
}
```

In the above class contains a Property "GrantType", we need to specify our user-defined value there, then its working fine.

```
public string GrantType {
    get { return "user-defined-value"; }
}
```

In my case, the value will be

```
public string GrantType {
    get { return "abc_service"; }
}
```